# Change app language without setting iPhone languge

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, localization, localizable.strings

Is there any way I change the app language from inside app only. Like if I select English the app behaves in english. If I select Hindi(from in app) than in that case my app restarts(I'll tell user with alert that app is going to restart) and storyboard loads hindi text using there strings file.

It means I don't want to set the language according to device's but according to in app selection.

Comment: see this post, https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/working-with-localization-in-swift-4a87f0d393a4

Comment: His Please check this video it solved your query :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9NV81z5ojo